# Android: Not able to draw on Canvas after set image as background

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an app like paint in Android. I am able to draw on the canvas. But when I set image from gallery as canvas background, I am not able to draw on it. My intention is, select an image from the gallery and draw on it.

below is my onDraw method.

```
private Bitmap mBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
        for (Path fp : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(fp.maskFilter);
            mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);

        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: you are saying the drawPath does not work?

Comment: I think yes but I am not sure whether it is the issue with drawPath

Comment: are you sure the `paths` is not empty?

Comment: Yes, I printed in logs and they are not empty.